# How to clear FORM after SUBMIT AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I've tried what everyone has been saying for this but i am un able to get the form to reset after it has submitted. Everything else works except this part. Just want the form to re-set again after it all runs. Thank you!

```js
<script>
$("#contactForm").submit(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var Name = $("#Name").val();
 var Phone = $("#Phone").val();
 var Company = $("#Company").val();
 var Website = $("#Website").val();
 var Service = $("#Service").val();
 var Message = $("#Message").val();
 var myData ={"Name":Name,"Phone":Phone,"Company":Company,"Website":Website,"Service":Service,"Message":Message}
 if(Name == "" || Phone == "" || Company == "" || Website == "" || Service == "" || Message == "" ) {
  $("#error_message").show().html("All Fields are Required");
 } else {
  $("#error_message").html("").hide();
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "submitAjax.php",
   data: myData,
   success: function(data){
    $("#contactForm").reset();
    $('#success_message').fadeIn().html(data);
    setTimeout(function() {
     $('#success_message').fadeOut("slow");
    }, 2000 );
    

   }
  });
 }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple

```
$("#contactForm")[0].reset();
```

or in vanilla javascript:

```
document.getElementById("#contactForm").reset();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can trigger reset function:

```
$('#form_id').trigger("reset");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this

```
<script>
$("#contactForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var Name = $("#Name").val();
    var Phone = $("#Phone").val();
    var Company = $("#Company").val();
    var Website = $("#Website").val();
    var Service = $("#Service").val();
    var Message = $("#Message").val();
    var myData ={"Name":Name,"Phone":Phone,"Company":Company,"Website":Website,"Service":Service,"Message":Message}
    if(Name == "" || Phone == "" || Company == "" || Website == "" || Service == "" || Message == "" ) {
        $("#error_message").show().html("All Fields are Required");
    } else {
        $("#error_message").html("").hide();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "submitAjax.php",
            data: myData,
            success: function(data){
                $("#contactForm").trigger("reset"); //reset form
                $('#success_message').fadeIn().html(data);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#success_message').fadeOut("slow");
                }, 2000 );


            }
        });
    }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Form value is still there even after document.getElementById("#contactForm").reset();

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#instantPrint").click(function (event) {

    //stop submit the form, we will post it manually.
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get form
    var form = $('#submitForm')[1];

   // Create an FormData object 
    var data = new FormData(form);


   // disabled the submit button
    $("#instantPrint").prop("disabled", true);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: '../card/card/print',
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 800000,
        success: function (data) {
          // $("#submitForm").trigger("reset");
          document.getElementById("#submitForm").reset();

            // // $("#output").text(data);
            // // console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
            // // $("#instantPrint").prop("disabled", false);
            // alert("Saved Successfully");
           

        },
        error: function (e) {

        //     $("#output").text(e.responseText);
        //     console.log("ERROR : ", e);
        //     $("#instantPrint").prop("disabled", false);

        // }
        alert("Unable to Save ");
    });
  

});

});
```

```html
<!--Card Layout Front -->
<div class="credit-card-wrap" id="card-view" style="top:20%;">
    <div class="mk-icon-world-map"></div>
    <div class="credit-card-inner">
        <header class="header">
            <div class="credit-logo">
                <div class="shape"><span class="txt"></span></div> <span class="text"></span>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="mk-icon-sim"><img id="previewLogo" src="" class="" height="50" width="65" alt="Avatar"></div>
        <div class="credit-font credit-card-number"><div></div></div> <!--JQUERY NUMBER HERE -->
        <footer class="footer">
            <div class="clearfix">
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <div class="credit-card-date"><span class="title">Exp</span><span class="credit-font"></span></div> <!-- JQUERY EXPIRY DATE  HERE -->
                    <div class="credit-font credit-author"></div><!-- JQUERY HOLDER NAMR HERE -->
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right"><div class="mk-icon-visa"><img id="previewSign"  src="" class="" bottom='-10px' height="25px" width="90px" alt="signature"></div></div> <!-- JQUERY IMAGE GOES  HERE -->
            <div class="mk-back-stripe"></div>
      </div>
</div>
</div>

<!--Card Layout Back --> <!--GOES HERE -->

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'id' => 'submitForm']]); ?>
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <div class="form-group"> 
                          
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'card_no')->textInput(['maxlength' => 16,'class'=>'form-control','id'=>'card-number']) ?>
    
                      </div>
                    </div>
            
</div>
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <div class="form-group"> 
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'class'=>'form-control','id'=>'card-name']) ?>
                      </div>
                    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <div class="form-group"> 
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'address')->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'class'=>'form-control']) ?>
                      </div>
                    </div>
</div>
                    
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <div class="form-group"> 
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'photoFile')->fileInput(['maxlength' => true,'class'=>'form-control','onchange'=>'previewLogo(previewLogo)','id'=>'photoFile']) ?>
                      </div>
                    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <div class="form-group"> 
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'signatureFile')->fileInput(['maxlength' => true,'class'=>'form-control','onchange'=>'previewSignature(previewSign)','id'=>'signatureFile']) ?>
                      </div>
                    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <div class="form-group"> 
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'class'=>'form-control']) ?>
                      </div>
                    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <div class="form-group"> 
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'phone')->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'class'=>'form-control']) ?>
                      </div>
                    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <div class="form-group"> 
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'citizen_no')->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'class'=>'form-control']) ?>
                      </div>
                    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <div class="form-group"> 
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'post')->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'class'=>'form-control']) ?>
                      </div>
                    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <div class="form-group"> 
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'issue_date')->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'class'=>'form-control']) ?>
                      </div>
                    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <div class="form-group"> 
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'expiry_date')->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'class'=>'form-control','id'=>'exp-date']) ?>
                      </div>
                    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <div class="form-group"> 
                      <?= $form->field($model, 'blood_group')->dropDownList(['O-','O+','A-','A+','B-','B+','AB-','AB+']) ?>
                      </div>
                    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <div class="form-group"> 
                      <?= $form->field($model, 'print_status')->dropDownList([1=>'Printed',0=>'Rejected']) ?>
                      </div>
                    </div>
</div> 
    <div class="col text-left">    
<?= Html::submitButton('Save and Print', ['class' => 'btn btn-outline-success','type'=>'submit','id'=>'instantPrint']) ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Do i need to explicitly define each and every input field ? because it contains image files too ! What if i use var myData=new FormData(#formId); to pass in data:myData

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".yourForm").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const dataString = $(this).serialize();
    const self = this;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/post",
        data: dataString,
        async: true,
        success: (res) => {
            // do something
            self.reset();
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```